# Socket doesn't work when using public ip on same machine

Tags: python, sockets, ip, public

I made a program using Python that should connect to the server using a socket. I run the script on the same machine and when I tried with private ip it worked but public doesn't.

Client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("46.126.xx.xxx",9454)) #I put the public ip of the server (same machine)

msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Server

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",9454))

s.listen(5)

while True:
clientsocket, address = s.accept()
print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
clientsocket.send(bytes("Welocme to the server", "utf-8"))
```

It does not give me any errors. I made lots of reasearch but couldn't figure out what the problem is.

Well I just put the public ip of the server in the client `socket.connect()` and expected it to connect but it didn't. I am running this on the same machine.

Comment: Are you behind a NAT router? Some routers won't do port forwarding for connections coming from the private network, only for connections on the WAN side.

Comment: Assuming a NAT router, did you set up port forwarding on your router from port 9454 to your private IP?

Comment: Also, if your firewall is a separate appliance, you'll need to add an exception. All modern firewalls I know of block WAN traffic by default. And unless you know what you're doing, opening up ports is probably a bad idea, especially if it's a home network.

Comment: If your router does not support [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning) you cannot connect to your public IP address from inside the network which is behind this public IP.

Comment: How can I found out if my router is a NAT router? @Barmar

Comment: @Axe319 Thank you for this information, I am very new to networking so thanks for warning me.

Comment: If it's a SOHO router, it's doing NAT.